# Handling !isset values without checking isset

Tags: php, exception, null, isset

I have an object that is pulled from an API that is similar to this structure:

```
class stdClass#544 (5) {
  public $id =>
  string(1) "4"
  public $name =>
  class stdClass#545 (6) {
    public $en =>
    string(6) "Test"
  }
  public $description =>
  class stdClass#546 (6) {
    public $en =>
    string(20) "My Description."
  }
}
```

However, the API is slightly inconsistent. Sometimes, certain objects have no `description` attributes:

```
class stdClass#544 (5) {
  public $id =>
  string(1) "7"
  public $name =>
  class stdClass#545 (6) {
    public $en =>
    string(6) "Another Test"
  }
}
```

As I'm looping through the API, I'm mapping values from the objects to an array:

```
$values = array();
foreach( $objects as $object ) {
  $values = array(
    'id' => $object->id,
    'name' => $object->name->en,
    'description' => $object->description->en,
  );
  someFunction($values);
}
```

However, since sometimes `description` is not a set/existing attribute of the object, this throws an Exception if `description` is missing.

What is the best approach to handle mapping of attributes that are sometimes not there? I can obviously check the existence of every single attribute before assigning them:

```
$values = array();
if ( isset($object->id) )
  $values['id'] = $object->id;

if ( isset($object->name) and isset($object->name->en) )
  $values['id'] = $object->name->en;

if ( isset($object->description) and isset($object->description->en) )
  $values['description'] = $object->description->en;
```

But that approach quickly becomes cumbersome and more difficult to maintain, especially when there are more attributes than what I listed. The above example is a simplified version of my problem. In reality there are many more attributes. So manually checking for the existence of attributes becomes much more of a pain, and even more so when they are nested attributes.

One simple solution I've found is to use the `@` symbol, which forces PHP to ignore exceptions:

```
$values = array();
foreach( $objects as $object ) {
  @$values = array(
    'id' => $object->id,
    'name' => $object->name->en,
    'description' => $object->description->en,
  );
  someFunction($values);
}
```

This results in `description` being `null` (which is ideal for me). No exception is thrown. However I'm pretty sure that `@` is to be used for debugging purposes and I don't think it's proper to use it in this way.

What is the best approach to handling this? Can I somehow easily set values in my array to null if the attribute/key doesn't exist in the object without having to manually check the existence of every single attribute?

Comment: If any attribute can be missing, you just have to check for it with `isset|empty`. Of course, it can be simplified with a converter function (that'll turn a potentially incomplete object into a safe one), but that still has to have a map of attributes to go through.

Comment: Minor sidenote: `isset($object->description->en)` will safely return `false` even if `description` property isn't set. It's one good thing of PHP that I often miss in JavaScript. )

Comment: I just realized that, thanks. That does help simplify it a little.

Answer (score 2):

You could define the keys you want to extract from the object in an array and then extract each key in a foreach loop.

**EDIT**

Just noticed you sometimes are accessing objects within objects. If you only need to go 1 level deep the example below should do it.

If the value you're extracting is a property of an object that is an additional level deep, then make the corresponding key an array of `keyName => subKeyName`.

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->id = 'hello';
$a->description = 'world';
$a->name = new stdClass();
$a->name->en = 'name';

$keys = ['id','description','notset',['name' => 'en']];
$value = [];
foreach($keys as $key) {

    if(is_array($key)) {
        $subkey = current($key);
        $key = key($key);
        $value[$key] = (isset($a->$key->$subkey))
          ? $a->$key->$subkey : null;
    }
    else {
        $value[$key] = (isset($a->$key)) 
          ? $a->$key : null;
    }
}

var_dump($value);
```